# How to submit reactive forms without validation in Angular 5?

Tags: angular, validation, onsubmit, angular-reactive-forms

It seems to me that, when using reactive forms the default behaviour is that it doesn't submits the data unless it is validated. Is there a way to switch this off, so I can submit data without needing to validate ?

Comment: Your assumption is wrong. You can do whetever you want in the function passed to ngSubmit, and this function is called whether or not the form is valid.

Comment: Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-k1qucg?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: I see. Could that be then cause I am not using ngSubmit ? This is how I do the submit: (submit)="onSubmit(updateBabyForm)"  and then my button type="submit"  or is this equivalent to ngSubmit ?

Comment: No, it's not equivalent. You're supposed to use ngSubmit.

Comment: and should the type the button be ngSubmit as well?

Comment: No. It should be submit (which is the default, so adding `type="submit"` is redundant).

Comment: ah yes, always forget that. Thank's for the overall clarification.

Answer (score 0):

As I am currently working on reactive forms, I can safely say that this I incorrect as JB Nizet already has left you as a comment. There is no particular need in using validation in Angular at all. Ultimately, your backend should do your actual validation.